# Simple Regex whitespace checker

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm just trying to 'continue' my loop if it's whitespace. My goal is to not allow any whitespace into the 'output'. I've tried all of the following but they all don't work.

```
var input = document.getElementById('textinput').value;
var lines = input.split('\n');
var output = '';
var patt1=/\s/g;

$.each(lines, function(key, line) {
    var parts = line.split(' ');
for (var iii=0; iii<parts.length; iii++)
{           
    if(parts[iii]==/\s/g)
        {continue;}

    output+= parts[iii];
}
```

I've also tried

```
if(patt1.test(parts[iii]) == true){continue;}
if(patt1.test(\'+parts[iii]+\') == true){continue;}
if (parts[iii]==" "|parts[iii]=="\n"|parts[iii]=="\t") continue;
if (parts[iii]=== |parts[iii]===\n|parts[iii]===\t){continue;}
```

Just in case it helps, if I input **chicken**, then **parts[iii]=='chicken'** evaluates as true.

Comment: If anyone's interested, [here's](https://github.com/Raindrop11/ConsoleLogAutotyper/blob/master/console%20log%20autotyper.js) the context/full source code (it's really short). I tried `input.replace(/\s+/g, '');` but it didn't work.